# C++ : Error LNK2019 using ArUCo-OpenGL- Freeglut in VisualStudio

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, freeglut, aruco

First time posting here, tell me if you need something else in order to help me!

I am trying to set up a simple AR application using ArUco and OpenGL in C++.

I build and installed ArUco, same for freeglut because glut is quite old by now but after solving a certain number of issues, I end up with only one issue that I can't seem to fix.

I already checked for include, library parameters or missing dll but I feel that everything is alright.
I'm building in debug mode x64, using ArUco with OpenCV vc16 (because it needs it) with every lib distinct (like "opencv_core412.lib") and the latest freeglut update available.

Here's the issue :

```
Erreur  LNK2019 symbole externe non résolu 
"public: void __cdecl aruco::MarkerDetector::detect(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<class aruco::Marker,class std::allocator<class aruco::Marker> > &,class cv::Mat,class cv::Mat,float,bool)" (?detect@MarkerDetector@aruco@@QEAAXAEBVMat@cv@@AEAV?$vector@VMarker@aruco@@V?$allocator@VMarker@aruco@@@std@@@std@@V34@2M_N@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: void __cdecl ArUco::idle(class cv::Mat)" (?idle@ArUco@@QEAAXVMat@cv@@@Z)
```

In English it is :

```
Error LNK2019   external symbol not resolved
"public: void __cdecl aruco::MarkerDetector::detect(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<class aruco::Marker,class std::allocator<class aruco::Marker> > &,class cv::Mat,class cv::Mat,float,bool)" (?detect@MarkerDetector@aruco@@QEAAXAEBVMat@cv@@AEAV?$vector@VMarker@aruco@@V?$allocator@VMarker@aruco@@@std@@@std@@V34@2M_N@Z) referenced in the function "public: void __cdecl ArUco::idle(class cv::Mat)" (?idle@ArUco@@QEAAXVMat@cv@@@Z)
```

Comment: You feel that your settings are correct, but since you don't share them no-one can tell. Could you share at least the aruco libraries you are linking with (since that seems to be where the issue is).

Comment: Hi :)
Thanks for answering!
I'm using the Aruco3112.lib ! I'm not sure I understood your questions well, I'm still a student, sorry !